# Yii2 add to head() and endBody()

Tags: yii2

In developing a site that can have multiple front-end themes, I am looking for a way to allow users on the back-end to manually inject code into the head and body. Two use cases are as follows:

Case 1 - Styles

1. In the back-end, the user selects a theme.
2. User likes the theme but would like to make links a different color.
3. Rather than copy and modify the theme, user can set custom code to execute at end of `<head>` tag.

Case 2 - Scripts

1. User wants to add custom JavaScript to end of document but requires an additional JavaScript library as well.
2. Rather than copy and modify the theme, user can set custom code to execute at and of `<body>` tag.

I understand that both of these specific cases could be accomplished (in part) with the use of `registerCss` and `registerJs` but those automatically wrap whatever is passed to them in `<style>` or `<script>` tags. I am hoping there is a way to just directly inject whatever is indicated directly into the `head()` or `endBody()` methods. The reason behind this is that I do not wish to limit what the user can inject (perhaps a script tag is needed in the head).

Currently, I am just storing the code-to-be-added in params then manually including them in each theme as follows:

```
<?php $this->endBody() ?>
<?= $this->params['theme_include_body_end'] ?>
```

This is undesirable as it can easily be forgotten when creating the theme. I would like to find a way to append my param value to the endBody() call automatically so whenever endBody() is called, my code is included (same for the head() call).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use own View component that overrides methods `renderHeadHtml()` and `renderBodyEndHtml()`. In these methods can be injected necessary code as you need:

```
namespace common/components;

class View extends \yii\web\View {

    /**
     * @var string Content that should be injected to end of `<head>` tag
     */
    public $injectToHead    = '';

    /**
     * @var string Content that should be injected to end of `<body>` tag
     */
    public $injectToBodyEnd = '';

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function renderHeadHtml()
    {
        return parent::renderHeadHtml() . $this->injectToHead;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function renderBodyEndHtml($ajaxMode)
    {
        return parent::renderBodyEndHtml(ajaxMode) . $this->injectToBodyEnd;
    }

}
```

In config file:

```
// ...
'components' => [
    // ...
    'view' => [
        'class' => '\common\components\View',
    ]
]
```

Somewhere in controller code:

```
\Yii::$app->view->injectToHead = '...';
\Yii::$app->view->injectToBodyEnd = '...';
```

Comment: This is a great start but it breaks down when I try to implement it with my modules. Because there is a back-end and front-end module, I cannot set the view at the component level or else it would apply to both modules. I needs to set the view class within the module. If I do that, I cannot set the injectToHeadEnd property from the controller. Any thoughts on adjusting this for working with multiple modules?

Comment: I don't undestood you problem: why you can't set? ) Your controller placed not in module?

Comment: The controller is within the module, but, the config file is for the entire app. I think I got this working. I had to set the view class within my module init() as follows: `Yii::$app->components = [ 'view' => [ 'class' => '\common\components\View' ] ];` Then, I could set the injected code as you have indicated, but, because I was overriding the view within my module, my IDE complained about it being an undefined field. Though the IDE thought it was undefined, it still worked.

Comment: If you don't want set component globally, you can simply define own `view` for the  necessary controller using `\yii\base\Controller::setView`. Additionally, you can create own parent controller class and override `\yii\base\Controller::getView` method (this method by default returns `Yii::$app->view;`).

Answer (score 4):

Yii2 already provide this functionality in **View Class** by using [**Block Widget**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-block.html)

you need 2 simple steps:

**1- (in required View file): in any given view**

```
<?php $this->beginBlock('block1'); ?>

...content of block1...

<?php $this->endBlock(); ?>

...

<?php $this->beginBlock('block3'); ?>

...content of block3...

<?php $this->endBlock(); ?>
```

**2- (in layout): define block name and its place in the layout page**

```
...

<?php if (isset($this->blocks['block1'])): ?>
    <?= $this->blocks['block1'] ?>
<?php else: ?>
    ... default content for block1 ...
<?php endif; ?>

...

<?php if (isset($this->blocks['block2'])): ?>
    <?= $this->blocks['block2'] ?>
<?php else: ?>
    ... default content for block2 ...
<?php endif; ?>

...

<?php if (isset($this->blocks['block3'])): ?>
    <?= $this->blocks['block3'] ?>
<?php else: ?>
    ... default content for block3 ...
<?php endif; ?>
...
```

Referance: Yii2 Guide

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#using-blocks

I hope this will help someone. Thank you.

Comment: Very nice, Thank You!

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Another, perhaps more simple alternative depending on your use case is to use the view events. You can inject different items at different parts of the page. For example:

```
Yii::$app->view->on(View::EVENT_END_BODY, function () {
    echo date('Y-m-d');
});
```

You can read more here: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-views#view-events

Comment: I like this solution because endBody() raises this event so it is directly tied into it and does not require extending any classes or whether layouts implement some param or block solution.

Comment: As a note, if you are using it on something being called from the view, you will need to place your call before the events registrar function endBody() or beginBody() and so on, as the event will already have triggered if you place it after this call